# How to get session's value

Tags: asp.net, session

MY applictaion =  Asp.net 4.0 + EF + WCF services + Database MYSQL all are different project(n tier architecture)

I am using sessionState mode="Custom"(storing session info in the DB) in my WEB project

My problem==> I know the session ID but how to get other session value in the other project like WCF Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Session cannot be shared between different applications that are hosted in different application pools in IIS. There are hacks that could allow you to do it but it is not recommended. The WCF service shouldn't depend on any session or it will be less reusable. The ASP.NET application which is consuming this service could pass all the necessary information when invoking a method.

Comment: Or, at the end of the day, you can even provide your own session state management mechanism without the ASP.NET compatibility mode, which will allow that WCF service to have sessions being hosted anywhere (IIS, Windows Service, host application...).

Comment: Ok, Is any alternate way by which i can get the session value?

Comment: @Venom, the whole point of my answer is that you shouldn't be doing this in the web service. Your web service shouldn't rely on a session. So simply have the ASP.NET client application pass it whatever information it needs. Remember that it's the ASP.NET application that has the session.